# bad interpreter: No such file or directory, update ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to update the ruby version, but after that
`rvm use 2.5.0 --default`

I get `-bash: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/gem: /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

very much need help.

Answer (score 3):

Install the ruby without binary like:

```
rvm reinstall 2.5.0 --disable-binary
```

This will work in your case

Comment: when using C9 this helped me ;) !

Comment: Thank you!! It worked for me. But I was also without the ruby version that my project was using.

Answer (score 0):

use following to see how the command is used

```
rvm use --help
```

you have to use either

```
rvm use <version>
rvm use 2.5.0
```

or if you want to use your default ruby version

```
rvm use default
```